# Sampling an N-dimensional normal distribution by sampling an angle and then a radius

Tags: probability-theory, statistics

Given samples from an N-dimensional normal distribution I can divide by the norm of each sample such that the samples lie uniformly over the surface of the $N-1$ sphere. If I then sample $u \in [0, 1]$ and take $u ^ {1 / N}$ as the radius I can generate samples uniformly throughout the volume of the sphere. I'm wondering how I could use the same process to generate an N-dimensional normal distribution?

My first thought was to first sample a point on the surface of the sphere, and a radius using the uniform distribution ($u^{1/N}$) and then transform this radius to a normal using the inverse cdf of a Half normal. The result is very close to the standard normal, but the variance is slightly smaller (the experiments don't match the theory here, but maybe I make a mistake).

How should I sample a radius such that the resulting samples follow a normal distribution?